# How do i replace following in notepad++ regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have SQL insert statement. One of values is date which i need to replace.

```
Insert into table (column_a, column_b) values ('test',to_date('01/DEC/15','DD/MON/RR'));
```

I have over 1000s of Insert SQL statement as above.

I want to replace value of column_b which has format `"to_date('01/DEC/15','DD/MON/RR')"` date can change within function. I want to replace column_b value with `"SYSDATE"` for all rows.

I tried following nothing is working.

```
^[to_date].*

/to_date([a-zA-Z0-9/,'])+/

/^to_date(.*$/
```

Can someone help?

Comment: thanks @Phil it works

Answer (score 2):

Insert into table (column_a, column_b) values ('test',to_date('01/DEC/15','DD/MON/RR'));
to_date('

If syntax of to_date function is correct throughout, this will satisfy your requirements:

```
to_date\([^)]+\)
```

What this regular expression means:

- `to_date` ← find this literal string
- `\(` ← followed by an open parenthesis. The backslash is an "escape character." You need to "escape the parenthesis," because parentheses are special characters in regex used to define a group.
- `[^)]` ← followed by 1 or more of any character *except* a closing parenthesis. The brackets indicate a character set `[]`. The leading caret `^` negates the character set ("not this set").
- `\)` ← followed by a closing parenthesis. Again, since this is meant to be a literal parenthesis and *not* the closing parenthesis of a regex group, the character must be escaped.

[image: Notepad++ Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Answer

```
to_date\(.+?\)
```

This matches...

- the literal `to_date(`
- `.+?` - a [non-greedy / lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) match for one or more of any character
- the literal `)`

---

Here's where you were going wrong

- Any use of `^` - this is the "start of string" anchor. Since the string you're looking for **never** appears at the start, this will never match.
- `[to_date].*` - this is a character class matching zero-or-more of the characters inside, ie "t", "o", "_", "d", "a", or "e"
- `to_date([a-zA-Z0-9/,'])+` - the parentheses here aren't escaped so instead of matching literal `(` and `)`, they form a capture group for the character class inside. Since you missed the literal parentheses, this will never match.
- `to_date(.*$` - this is an invalid expression as you're missing the closing `)` for the capture group

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in this situation, **the simplest regular expression** is:

```
to_date.{25}
```

This expression means *literal string "to_date" and 25 characters after it*.

It will work.